# STM32373c Eval board - USB CDC does not enumerate

Tags: usb, stm32, usbserial, cdc

I have a STM32373c-eval board and just getting started.
I have installed Truestudio, CubeMX and ST flash utility on my ubuntu 16.04 cause I don't have access to Keil or a Windows PC.

Using CubeMX I generated a code for LED toggle and it worked fine.
Now I did the same for USB CDC - checked the Device(FS), RCC clock at High Speed (Crystal) and
under Middlewares I have set Communication Device Class (COM Port) for Class For FS IP and USB clock is at 48Mhz.

I did no modifications in the generated code just flashed it and connected the kit to my Ubuntu alas I don't see the enumeration.
I also checked for any jumper settings for USB but there ain't any.

Can any one help me out in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how USB works? If not it might be a bit dufficult to to start it out of the box. One suggestion - if you are lucky the problem lies in the too slow initialization and the descriptor request is not handled. you can check it by connecting d+ to the ground (when device is up of course) forcing the enumeration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem was an additional GPIO pin in the schematics that was driving the USB pin low. -.-